# Communication between App and iWatch: is using app group the only way?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, watchkit, ios-app-group

I have an iPhone app that performs some computations. It works well. Now I'd like to create a WatchKit extension and target in order to control the start of the computations and display the results once the computations are finished as well as update the progress (e.g. percentage completed when Watch app is displayed, and send a notification from the iPhone app to the iWatch when the progress reaches a significant percentage mark).

I have found [some tutorials](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions) that explain to use **NSUserDefaults** and **initWithSuitName** providing an **app group** and then add the data object to synchronise. I could use KVO to display a percentage label on the Watch.

As I am exploring the possible architectures here, are you aware of some **alternative methods** to achieve this? Is using **app group** the method that Apple recommends?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole

Comment: Also interesing stuff here: http://fancypixel.github.io/blog/2015/03/29/share-data-between-watchkit-and-your-app-with-realm/

Answer (score 0):

You can use open app to launch your computation. then you can send information  with handoff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is handoff? I would like to have a button that triggers the action on the app that is already open. Could you include some sample code or tutorial links?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps

After setting Watch kit session and creating data dictionary you can use send message with this

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:<Your Dictionary> replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage) {

        //You task on completion

    } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        if (error)
        {
            //Handle the error
        }
    }];
```

at watch extension side
You can set delegate method

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *replyMessage))replyHandler
{
     //Handle the received data
}
```

And you are done

Answer (score 0):

App groups no longer work above watchOS 1. You need to use `WatchConnectivity` framework. Once you get the values in watch you can use Reactive or Rx to update the values instead of KVO.

**Helpful Links:**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity

https://kristina.io/watchos-2-how-to-communicate-between-devices-using-watch-connectivity/

https://www.natashatherobot.com/watchconnectivity-application-context/